Text formatting in R officer (justify, font size)
I've been trying to use the R officer package to create a word document using only code (without using a word template, as the idea is to make the code reproducible even if other people dont have the original template)
im now having trouble formatting the texts, in order for them to be justified (like the justify format in word) and when the document is created, being in calibri font and the fontsize being 12. this is the code i have now:
if (!requireNamespace("officer", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("officer")
}
library(officer)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)



# create new word document
new.word.doc=function(){
  my.doc=read_docx()
  return(my.doc)
}

doc=new.word.doc()

doc <- doc %>%
  body_add_par("")  %>%
  body_add("Lorem ipsum", style = "Normal", prop = fp_text(color = "black", bold = TRUE, font.size = 14, font.family = "calibri")) %>%
  body_add_par("")  %>%
  body_add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", style = "Justify", prop = fp_text(color = "black", bold = FALSE, font.size = 12, font.family = "calibri"))

what should i change? that code doesnt work, and when i chage the style to "Normal" the code does not pick up the font size or the font family

Try adding a formatted paragraph like so:
library(officer)
library(stringi)

read_docx() |>
  body_add(
    fpar(
      stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1),
      fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "justify"),
      fp_t = fp_text(font.size = 12, font.family = "Calibri")
    )
  ) |>
  print("justified.docx")

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0

